# Loop and bifurcation diagram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm writing a script which plots the bifurcation diagram of a damped pendulum with a small direct forcing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
epsi = 0.01
# Declare the model
f_dir = np.arange(0,1.3,0.01)
A_s = np.zeros(len(f_dir))

i = 0
for f in f_dir:
 def myModel(y, t):

    dy0 = y[1]
    dy1 = -epsi*y[1]-np.sin(y[0]) - f*np.cos((1.01)*t)*np.cos(y[0])
    return [dy0, dy1]
    time = np.arange(0.0, 2000,0.01)
    yinit = np.array([np.pi/2, 0])
    y = odeint(myModel, yinit, time)

    A_s.insert(i,np.abs(np.max(y[-600:-1,0])- np.min(y[-600:-1,0])))

 i += 1


plt.plot(f_dir,A_s,'*')
plt.xlabel(r'$f_s$')
plt.ylabel(r'$A_s$')
plt.hold
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I am not inserting anything into `A_s`, and I do not know why because the variable `i` is increased at each step of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow your code, but this is probably closer to what you want. You only need to define your model once, even if `f` is a variable argument: you can pass such arguments to `odeint` in the `args` tuple and they get handed on to the model function.

Also note that NumPy arrays don't have an `insert` method.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
epsi = 0.01
# Declare the model
f_dir = np.arange(0,1.3,0.01)
A_s = np.zeros(len(f_dir))

def myModel(y, t, f):
    dy0 = y[1]
    dy1 = -epsi*y[1]-np.sin(y[0]) - f*np.cos((1.01)*t)*np.cos(y[0])
    return [dy0, dy1]

i = 0
for f in f_dir:
    time = np.arange(0.0, 2000,0.01)
    yinit = np.array([np.pi/2, 0])
    y = odeint(myModel, yinit, time, args=(f,))
    A_s[i] = np.abs(np.max(y[-600:-1,0])- np.min(y[-600:-1,0]))
    i += 1


plt.plot(f_dir,A_s,'*')
plt.xlabel(r'$f_s$')
plt.ylabel(r'$A_s$')
plt.hold
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok I understand what you have done, now it works correctly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You defined the myModel function, but it's not actually being called anywhere - it's just referenced from within the function itself.

Comment: The `myModel` function object is passed to `odeint` which does call it.

Comment: That's true in the solution you offered, but in the posted question, odeint isn't called either (since it happens inside myModel)... unless I'm really missing something here